# Use access token from Keycloak social login to consume Google API in Java

Tags: java, spring-security, google-api, keycloak, jhipster

I have 2 pieces of code I want to integrate.

1. I have a working Google API (Youtube) integration that gets some user related information using the correct scopes while asking for authentication.

```
public YouTube getService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    final NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    return new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials())
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
        .build();
}
```

```
private Credential getCredentials() throws IOException {
    // With the GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow you can create a Credential
    Credential credential = authorizationCodeFlow.loadCredential(userService.getUserWithAuthorities().get().getId().toString());

    if (credential == null) {
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl authorizationUrl = authorizationCodeFlow.newAuthorizationUrl();
        Map<String, String> state = Map.of("userId", userService.getUserWithAuthorities().get().getId().toString());
        authorizationUrl.setState(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(state));
        authorizationUrl.setRedirectUri(CALLBACK_URL);
        System.out.println("REDIRECTURL: " + authorizationUrl); //ToDo: remove
        throw new YtUnauthorizedException(authorizationUrl.toString());
    }
    return credential;
}
```

2. I have a spring security / keycloack integration with social login using jhipster generated code.

Now I want to use the Google API code with the access token from Spring Security / Keycloak but none of the options I tried worked.

Following [this article](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/06/using-spring-security-5-to-integrate-with-oauth-2-secured-services-such-as-facebook-and-github#:%7E:text=Accessing%20API%20resources)
I tried this code:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(getAccessToken());
```

```
private String getAccessToken(){
    Authentication authentication =
        SecurityContextHolder
            .getContext()
            .getAuthentication();

    OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauthToken =
        (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;


    OAuth2AuthorizedClient client =
        clientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
            oauthToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(),
            oauthToken.getName());

    return client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
}
```

But it doesn't work. I suspect I'm getting the access token of Keycloak but not Google. Any idea how I can use Google API with this setup?

Answer (score 1):

Google does not know about your Keycloak instance and won't accept the access-tokens it emitted.

When you "login with Google" against a Keycloak instance, it checks an ID token emitted by Google and creates its own set of tokens (access, refresh and ID). Just open one of this tokens in https://jwt.io (or introspect it if it is opaque) and check the `iss` and `aud` claim values. This new tokens are to be used on your own applications (ID & refresh on clients, access on resource-servers), not on Google API.

To query Google API, two cases:

- the request is not done on behalf of a specific user (you registered a Google client app that sends requests in its own name) => configure the REST client in your back-end with client-credentials so that it gets a fresh access-token before emitting requests to Google
- the request is made on behalf of the end-user => you need an access-token for that user => request it from your client app (this could even be silent as your user already identified against Google) and send the request from the client directly or send Google access-token in a request body to your resource-server so that it can set its own request to with this "Google" token as authorization header